# How to know the number of circuits through my Tor relay(OR)?

Tags: relays, configuration, circuit

Can anyone tell me how to know how many circuits are being build through my Tor relay(OR)? I am using vidalia.

Comment: Which Tor package and version did you install, on which platform? Are you running just a client, non-exit or exit node?

Comment: i am running version 0.2.4.21 (git-c5a648cc6f218339) on Ubuntu 12.04 as an exit node. Vidalia version is 0.2.21

Comment: I run SETEVENTS EXTENDED ORCONN command from the terminal after authentication. In 4.1.3 of <https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/control-spec.txt>, under OR Connection status changed, the syntax is :

"650" SP "ORCONN" SP (LongName / Target) SP ORStatus [ SP "REASON=" Reason ] [ SP "NCIRCS=" NumCircuits ] [ SP "ID=" ConnID ] CRLF
so it says that we can get number of circuits also. But when I run the command,I can get all the information of above syntax except numcircuits.